# UIButton suddenly stops working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

So I'm having issues with the buttons for the filters in my photo app. I'm not exactly sure why, but they've suddenly stopped working. The selector is not being called when they're tapped, but I have no idea why. They were working just fine a few days ago, but for some reason they're not now. I've checked the UIView subviews array, verified that it's right on top. I need a way to see if, for some reason, the touches are not making it to the button. I'm not sure how to do this.

I wish I had more information to give, but this is all I've got. I hope someone has some suggestions because I'm at wit's end with it.

Thanks in advance!

Button Creation Method:

```
-(void)createFilterButtonsForThumbnail:(UIImage *)thumbnail
{
    UIView *filtersContainer = self.filterContainer;
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(kFilterFrameThickness, kFilterFrameThickness,
                                    thumbnail.size.width, thumbnail.size.height);

    CGFloat frameWidth = thumbnail.size.width+(2*kFilterFrameThickness);
    CGFloat frameHeight = kFilterPickerHeight;

    UIEdgeInsets backgroundInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, kFilterFrameThickness, 0, kFilterFrameThickness);
    UIImage *buttonBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"FilmReel"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:backgroundInsets];

    for (int i = 0;i<(self.filterPaths.count+kFilterNonLookups+1);i++){


        UIImageView *buttonBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kFilterSidePadding+(i*(frameWidth+kFilterSidePadding)),
                                                                            0,
                                                                            frameWidth,
                                                                            frameHeight)];
        [buttonBackground setImage:buttonBackgroundImage];

        UIButton *thumbnailButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
        UIImage *filteredThumbnail = [self applyFilterAtIndex:i ToImage:thumbnail];

        [thumbnailButton setImage:filteredThumbnail forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [thumbnailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(filterSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [thumbnailButton setTag:i];

        [buttonBackground addSubview:thumbnailButton];
        [filtersContainer addSubview:buttonBackground];
        if ((i > (kFilterProMinimumIndex)) && ([self isProVersion]) == NO){
            UIImageView *proTag = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
            CGRect proFrame = CGRectMake(buttonFrame.origin.x,
                                         buttonFrame.origin.y + buttonFrame.size.height - kFilterProIconHeight-kFilterFrameThickness,
                                         kFilterProIconWidth,
                                         kFilterProIconHeight);
            [proTag setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
            [proTag setFrame:proFrame];
            [thumbnailButton addSubview:proTag];
            [self.filterProTags addObject:proTag];
        }
    }
}
```

Selector Method:

```
-(void)filterSelected:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSLog(@"Pressed button for index %i",button.tag);
    int buttonTag = button.tag;
    if ((buttonTag < kFilterProMinimumIndex+1) || ([self isProVersion] == YES)){
        [self.imageView setImage:[self applyFilterAtIndex:buttonTag ToImage:self.workingImage]];
    }
    else {
        [self processProPurchaseAfterAlert];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a couple issues in this, but I'm not sure which ones are causing it to break. First, you should instantiate your button using `buttonWithType:` on UIButton:

```
UIButton *thumbnailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[thumbnailButton setFrame:buttonFrame]
```

The reason for this is UIButton is a class cluster, and you should let the OS give you the correct button.

Secondly, you're adding the Button as a Subview of an UIImageView, which by default, has `userInteractionEnabled` set to [NO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/userInteractionEnabled).

> This property is inherited from the UIView parent class. This class
>   changes the default value of this property to NO.

You should have the button be one large button, with the background of the button be the image you want it to be.

Comment: I had actually tried the top part and it didn't fix it so I erased it. I put it back for convention's sake though.But the userInteractionEnabled set to YES on both the background and the button definitely fixed this. Thank you so much, I couldn't figure this out!